# Derivation of Fisher information

Tags: fisher-information

The Fisher information is derived from the second moment of the log likelihood equation.  I am unable to follow the step below (from  wiki) moving from the Expectation of the second partial derivative to the (chain rule result?) difference of a second order partial derivative and the square of the first order partial derivative.

If someone were feeling "talkative" and would be willing to fill in the blanks there - it would be appreciated.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *is* a chain rule problem.

Given

```
d(log(x))/dx = 1/x
```

and

```
 d(log(f(x))/dx = [d(f(x))/dx] / x
```

and: starting with the first order derivative:

[image]

Let us now take the *second* partial derivative by re-differentiating that first order one. This requires the chain rule:

```
d(f(a)f(b))/ dx  = d(f(a))/dx f(b) + f(a) d(f(b))/dx
```

Where we set

```
f(a) =
```

[image]

```
f(b) = 1/ (f(X; theta)  = f(X;theta)**-1
```

The final result then follows.